# WSL start ends in black screen

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have to admit I tried a lot arrount WSL with ubuntu as the network stack didn' work at all

so I tried as admin

```
wsl --shutdown
wsl /u Ubuntu
wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
```

now Ubuntu starts in a black screen and stops there.

It's on Windows 10

wsl --status shows.

```
Standard Distribution: Ubuntu
Standardversion: 2

Windows-Subsystem for Linux last Update 23.06.2022
automatic updates activated

Kernel-Version: 5.10.102.1
```

wsl -l -v shows

```
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Stopped         2
```

Is there a way to repair that ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `wsl /u Ubuntu`?  That's not a valid flag, AFAIK?  What was the result/output of that command?

Comment: tried to remove the old Ubuntu in wsl. Output was nothing

Comment: A few more questions -- (1) What Windows version?  (2) What does `wsl --status` show?  (3) What does `wsl -l -v` show?  --- Please edit your question to include that info.  Note that (2) may not work depending on the Windows version.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds updated the question for that.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4569

Comment: @Gantendo thanks a lot.  One of the solutions was to mark the blank screen. Very odd but worked quite well. I am now back in WSL. Still the network does not work at all and the exit looks very odd. that will be another case. Thanks to you all !

Comment: user3732793, feel free to write your own answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to mark the blank screen with the left mouse button.

Again not fully happy but a solution to the blank screen issue.